# Cannot assign to INTENT (IN) variable x at (1) - How can this be solved?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, pgi

While compiling a Fortran program with gfortran (mpif90), I encounter the following error:

```
Error: Cannot assign to INTENT (IN) variable 'x' at (1)
make[2]: [module.o] Error 1 (ignored)
```

When I compile this program with PGI, I do not receive this error.

I've got two questions regarding this.

1. What is the meaning of this error?
2. How can I make gfortran and mpif90 compile this module file similarly to PGI? Is there a flag that I can pass to tell the gfortran compiler not to worry about this?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you'd shown us the code this might be more than a guess but here goes ...

You have a procedure, either a function or a subroutine, something like

```
integer function my_func(x)
    real, intent(in) :: x
    ...
    x = a_value
    my_func = 2
end function my_func
```

The statement `real, intent(in) :: x` tells the compiler that the function will not attempt to alter the argument `x`.  And then, bang, in `x = a_value`, the function goes right ahead and attempts to alter the argument.

This behaviour by the compiler is a tremendous aid to safe programming and if the PGI compiler really doesn't raise an error on encountering such code then (a) it is in error, the standard requires that it should and (b) you should not be using an unsafe compiler.

Other compilers are quite right to raise this error and even if I knew a way to tell a compiler not to I wouldn't share it with you.  It would be like teaching you how to remove the safety guard from a bacon-slicing machine.

Now, show us your code and one of us can give you a proper diagnosis.

Comment: Not sure the reason for the downvote on this, it seems to be a very good guess given the complete lack of code in the OP.

Comment: You're completely right. In the beginning of the module file we have INTENT(IN) declared for x and then later, x is assigned. For some reason I missed this when looking at the code. I'd up-vote if I had the street cred for it! The file is 308 lines. If you think I should post it, I will.

Comment: Meh, since my guess was on target there's not much need to post the whole code, not even a snippet.  When you have the rep come back and upvote if you like, but even at your current rep you should still be able to accept the answer.